# Change properties to several merged cells using "for each" takes too long VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I finally got able to program a code to do several operations in merged cells, however it takes too long and I need the cells to be merged.

The macro activates when someone clicks on a button and it's intended to block the some cells if a checkbox is activated, and block another set of cells when is not.

The first "If" is the evaluation of the checkbox. Then it does some operations to some merged cells. Tho code works bur the problems comes with the use of the "For each" statements because it makes the macro run really slow.

An alternative is just select each merged cell and apply the changes one by one to avoid the loops, but that will take some a lot of time (this is just a part of the code).

```
dim rng as Range

...
with some_worksheet
If .Shapes("checkbox1").ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then

    For Each rng In .Range("K20:X33")
        rng.MergeArea.Locked = False
    Next rng
        .Range("U29").MergeArea.ClearContents
        For Each rng In .Range("K32:X33")
            rng.MergeArea.ClearContents
        Next rng
    For Each rng In .Range("L26:X33")
        rng.MergeArea.Locked = True
    Next rng
Else
    For Each rng In .Range("K20:X33")
        rng.MergeArea.Locked = False
    Next rng

    For Each rng In .Range("K20:U25")
        rng.MergeArea.ClearContents
    Next rng
    For Each rng In .Range("K28:T31")
        rng.Locked = True
    Next rng
    For Each rng In .Range("K20:AC27")
        rng.Locked = True
    Next rng

    .Range("K28").MergeArea.Locked = True
    .Range("K29").MergeArea.Locked = True
    For Each rng In .Range("K30:AC31")
        rng.Locked = True
    Next rng
End If
End With
...
End Sub
```

[image]

Here's the Excel Screen Display(it also needs to be like that). 
The program takes too long because it loops through a LOT of ranges due to the Display.
I'll help to further explain what the macros does.

The grey are the ranges that need to be locked and cleared.

When I click "selection1":

It should unlock all the grey areas, clear the grey fields below the "selection2" selection button, the lock those cells and leave the fields "K20:U25" free to edit.

When I click "selection2" should do the opposite.

Thanks for the quick responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies.
Application.ScreenUpdating helped but the time was still huge.

What I did was to do little loops between the cells instead of using a "For Each" statement and go through all those cells.

```
    Dim intloop as integer
    ...
    'Unblock
    if ("checkbox1").ControlFormat.Value = xlOn then
    For intLoop = 0 To 4
        .Range("K2" & intLoop).MergeArea.Locked = False
        .Range("U2" & intLoop).MergeArea.Locked = False
    Next intLoop
    For intLoop = 2 To 3
        .Range("K3" & intLoop).MergeArea.Locked = False
        .Range("U3" & intLoop).MergeArea.Locked = False
    Next intLoop
    .Range("U28").MergeArea.Locked = False
    .Range("U29").MergeArea.Locked = False
    'Data delete
    .Range("U28").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    .Range("U29").MergeArea.ClearContents
    For intLoop = 2 To 3
        .Range("K3" & intLoop).MergeArea.ClearContents
        .Range("U3" & intLoop).MergeArea.ClearContents
    Next intLoop
    'Block
    For intLoop = 2 To 3
        .Range("K3" & intLoop).MergeArea.Locked = True
        .Range("U3" & intLoop).MergeArea.Locked = True
    Next intLoop
    .Range("U28").MergeArea.Locked = True
    .Range("U29").MergeArea.Locked = True
Else
    'Unblock
    For intLoop = 0 To 4
        .Range("K2" & intLoop).MergeArea.Locked = False
        .Range("U2" & intLoop).MergeArea.Locked = False
    Next intLoop
    For intLoop = 2 To 3
        .Range("K3" & intLoop).MergeArea.Locked = False
        .Range("U3" & intLoop).MergeArea.Locked = False
    Next intLoop
    .Range("U28").MergeArea.Locked = False
    .Range("U29").MergeArea.Locked = False
    'Data delete
    .Range("U28").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    For intLoop = 0 To 4
        .Range("K2" & intLoop).MergeArea.ClearContents
        .Range("U2" & intLoop).MergeArea.ClearContents
    Next intLoop
    'Block
    For intLoop = 0 To 4
        .Range("K2" & intLoop).MergeArea.Locked = True
        .Range("U2" & intLoop).MergeArea.Locked = True
    Next intLoop
    End if
    ...
    End sub
```

As you see the code is longer but is way faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

In the beginning of your Function, and

```
On Error GoTo HERE
: HERE
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Before `End Sub`

It basically freeze any update in excel window before the code finish running. It will significantly speed up the running time, especially if there is many cell formatting in the code.

On Error make sure that Excel will unfreeze even if your code stops midway